# How do I make json get to work in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I followed information on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369377/how-to-use-http-get-in-angularjs-correctly-in-specific-for-an-external-api-cal)
But it doesn't work in my situation.
Chrome Inspector console says "**ReferenceError: dataResponse is not defined**"
maybe that is the problem?

I am trying to GET this JSON from url:

```
[{"app_id":1,"app_name":"oh yeeah","app_description":"desc","app_price":111,"is_activated":false,"video":"videolink"},{"app_id":2,"app_name":"oh yeaaaeah","app_description":"ewaewq","app_price":222,"is_activated":false,"video":"fuck off"},{"app_id":3,"app_name":"oh yeaaaeah","app_description":"ewaewq","app_price":333,"is_activated":false,"video":"fuck off"}]
```

This is my javascript code

```
    var appstore = angular.module('appstore', []);

appstore.service('dataService', function($http) {
    delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    this.getData = function(callbackFunc) {
        $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/administrator/components/com_apps/loadAppsJson.php'
    }).success(function(data){
        callbackFunc(data);
    }).error(function(){
        alert("error");
    });
    }
});

appstore.controller('app_Ctrl', function($scope, dataService) {

  $scope.apps = [
                  {app_id:1, app_name:'oh yeah', app_description:'$app_description', app_price:111, is_activated:false, video:'$videolink'},
                  {app_id:2, app_name:'oh yeah', app_description:'$app_description', app_price:111, is_activated:false, video:'$videolink'},
                  {app_id:3, app_name:'oh yeah', app_description:'$app_description', app_price:111, is_activated:false, video:'$videolink'},
                ];

    //$scope.apps = null;
    dataService.getData(function(dataResponse) {
        $scope.apps = dataResponse; 
        alert(dataResponse);
    });
    console.log(dataResponse);
    console.log($scope.apps);



    //get images thumbs
    for(app = 0; app <= $scope.apps.length-1; app++) {
        $scope.apps[app].thumb = ("000" + $scope.apps[app].app_id).slice(-3);
    }

    //separate apps to columns
    var columns = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.apps.length; i++ ) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) columns.push([]);
        columns[columns.length-1].push($scope.apps[i]);
    }
    $scope.columns = columns;
    });
```

My HTML view

```
<div ng-controller="app_Ctrl">
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row">

<div class="row" ng-repeat="apps in columns">
<div id="app_id_{{ app.app_id }}" class="col-lg-4" ng-repeat="app in apps | filter:search">
    <div class="thumbnail" ng-class="app.is_activated ? 'activated' : ''">
        <a href="{{ app.video }}/&hd=1&fs=1&width=90%&height=90%&resize_to=height&showinfo=0" class="app_video_stitok movie-video help-video" rel="prettyPhoto"></a>
        <a href="index2.php?option=com_apps&amp;mode=detail&amp;id={{ app.app_id }}" class="app_detail_link_absolute"><!-- --></a>
        <a href="index2.php?option=com_apps&amp;mode=detail&amp;id={{ app.app_id }}" class="app_detail_link"><img ng-src="/images/apps/app_images/{{ app.thumb }}_thumb.jpg" alt="{{ app.app_name }}" title="{{ app.app_name }}"></a>
        <div class="caption">
            <h3><a href="index2.php?option=com_apps&amp;mode=detail&amp;id={{ app.app_id }}">{{ app.app_name }}</a></h3>
            <p class="app_price">{{ app.app_price }} €</p>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
            <p class="app_card_description">{{ app.app_description | limitTo:100 }}...</p>
            <a href="index2.php?option=com_apps&amp;mode=detail&amp;id={{ app.app_id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Info</a>
            <a href="{{ app.video }}/&hd=1&fs=1&width=90%&height=90%&resize_to=height&showinfo=0" title="video" class="movie-video help-video btn btn-info" style="display:inline !important; z-index: 100;" rel="prettyPhoto">Video <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></span></a>
            <a href="index2.php?option=com_apps&amp;mode=detail&amp;type=ajax&amp;id={{ app.app_id }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-activate" ng-class="app.is_activated ? 'btn-activated' : ''">{{ app.is_activated ? 'Aktivované' : 'Aktivovať' }}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that error is because you are doing console.log after `getData` function.

Comment: what is your callback function exactly ? put the console log inside your success()`{console.log('response : ' + data);}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on what @Mritunjay said in the comments; review this code with comments:

```
dataService.getData(
// this is your callback function which has an argument for dataResponse
// the dataResponse variable will only be defined within the Call back function
function(dataResponse) {
    $scope.apps = dataResponse; 
    alert(dataResponse);
// The Curly Brackets that follow mark the end of the callback handler method  
});
// This log statement is not in the callback handler and there is no defined dataResponse variable which is probably why you got an error in the console
console.log(dataResponse);
```

You can fix this by moving the dataResponse log into the callback method, like this:

```
dataService.getData(function(dataResponse) {
    $scope.apps = dataResponse; 
    alert(dataResponse);
    console.log(dataResponse);
});
```

There appear to be other problems with your code, in that you are trying to access $scope.apps before the data is returned; which will hinder your processing.  Easiest approach would be to move that processing into the result handler:

```
// define $scope.columns outside of the result handler
$scope.columns = [];
// call to method in service
dataService.getData(function(dataResponse) {
    $scope.apps = dataResponse; 
    alert(dataResponse);
    console.log(dataResponse);

    // inside the result handler; you run this code after $scope.apps is defined:
    for(app = 0; app <= $scope.apps.length-1; app++) {
       $scope.apps[app].thumb = ("000" + $scope.apps[app].app_id).slice(-3);
    }

    //separate apps to columns
    var columns = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.apps.length; i++ ) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) columns.push([]);
        columns[columns.length-1].push($scope.apps[i]);
    }
    $scope.columns = columns;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what promises and asynchronous calls are all about.

```
console.log(dataResponse);
console.log($scope.apps);
```

The first one won't work because dataResource is a private variable and not part of the same scope you're trying to print.
The second one won't work either because that get's populated at future time (after X seconds), after the $http request is finished so it will only be availableat that point.

One way to do something after the object is populated is to use

```
$scope.$watch("apps", function (){
// do stuff
});
```