# Getting data from an Angular factory and sharing data to a controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

Im currently messing around learning Angular.  I have a controller thats hooked up to a radial progress bubble, i am creating a factory that uses $http to grab some dummy data from data.json I inject the factory into my controller and set that data into a variable so i can use it inside some other objects. To be exact, i want to take the first element of the returned array from my json file as the dashOffset property on the circle object.  The current console.log inside my controller prints Undefined but the console.log in my factory prints out the correct array.

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ui.router'])
.factory('Data', function($http){
    return {
        getData : function(callback){
            $http.get('data.json').success(function(res){
                console.log(res)
            });
        }
    }



})
.controller('radial', function($scope, Data){
    $scope.ryan = Data.getData();

    console.log($scope.ryan);


    $scope.circle = {
        size : 110,
        stroke : '#2C3E50',
        strokeWidth : 10,
        radius : 48,
        dashArray : Math.PI * 2 * 48,
        dashOffset : (Math.PI * 2 * 48)
    }
    $scope.circleBG = {
        size : 110,
        stroke : '#2C3E50',
        strokeWidth : 10,
        radius : 48,
        dashArray : Math.PI * 2 * 48,
        dashOffset : (Math.PI * 2 * 48)
    }

});
```

Comment: That is because you are really not returning anything from your factory method

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use HTTP.GET in AngularJS correctly? In specific, for an external API call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369377/how-to-use-http-get-in-angularjs-correctly-in-specific-for-an-external-api-cal)

Comment: Oh, i see, but even when i add return res to the end of the success function it still prints undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things 
    1->you are not really returning anything in your getData method 
    2-> getData is an asynchronous operation so by the time the function returns there is no data to view yet

there are 2 ways of achiving what you want

```
1->callbacks
2-> promises
```

using callbacks you can do something like
 in your controller

assuming you return the $http.get you can do

```
//using success callback
Data.getData()
.success(function(data){
     $scope.ryan=data;
     console.log($scope.ryan)
});

//using promises

Data.getData()
.then(function(response){
    return response.data
})
.then(function(ryan){
   $scope.ryan=ryan;
   console.log(ryan)
})
```

for more on this review

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http