# How to return a function into a scoped variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use a factory that I can assign to a scoped angular variable. However, whenever I attemp to attach this and use console.log to return this variable I am am returned with the function as text and not as a value. Is there a way I can get this fixed?

========== JS ==========

```
 annApp.factory('rssFeed', function()
  {
    return function()
    {
      var events = [];
       $.get('xmlfile',
       function(xml)
    {
    var json = $.xml2json(xml); 
    jsonb = JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 3 );
   // var events = []; 
      var description = json['#document']['rss']['channel']['item']['description'];
      var title = json['#document']['rss']['channel']['item']['title'];
      var date = json['#document']['rss']['channel']['item']['pubDate'];
      events.push({'title': title, 'description':description, 'date': date});   
      return events;
   });
   return events; 
 }

annApp.controller('calendar', ['$scope', 'rssFeed', function($scope, rssFeed){
  $scope.events = rssFeed;
  console.log($scope.events);
}]);
```

Comment: Are you just looking to call the rssFeed factory and log it to console? In that case you need to invoke the function `console.log($scope.events());` Also, I believe the line after `return events;` should be `};});`

Comment: Here's a fiddle that's correctly returning the function: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/19871/

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to print out the reference to the function itself, then what you have is correct (other than the syntax error mentioned by DenimChicken):

```
annApp.factory('rssFeed', function(){
    return function(){
        var events = [];
        $.get('xmlfile', function(xml){
            var json = $.xml2json(xml); 
            jsonb = JSON.stringify(json, undefined, 3 );
            var description = json['#document']['rss']['channel']['item']['description'];
            var title = json['#document']['rss']['channel']['item']['title'];
            var date = json['#document']['rss']['channel']['item']['pubDate'];
            events.push({'title': title, 'description':description, 'date': date});   
        });
        return events; 
    };
}); // <-- added this
```

If you're trying to print out the *return value* from the function, then you need to call the function by putting parentheses after the name:

```
console.log($scope.events());
```

However, since `$.get` is asynchronous, you should either pass in a callback and call it when the request is complete, or use promises.

Comment: I was able to get the callback function to work properly using another stackoverflow question found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369377/how-to-use-http-get-in-angularjs-correctly-in-specific-for-an-external-api-cal.

Comment: After being able to create the callback I am not able to display the object data on the page however, I am able to return the object to the console window. Ideas?

Comment: Can't say without seeing your code. If you put it in a jsfiddle, post the link and I'll take a look.

Comment: You were using the jQuery `$.get` ajax method, which does not notify Angular that it needs to update its bindings. If you change it to use Angular's `$http` provider, it will work. (http://jsfiddle.net/9rv9ahcp/2/)

Comment: Also, it looks like the URL you're using is in error.

Comment: Sorry about this. I have this URL sitting behind a firewall.

Comment: How would I be able to use $http when the data I am getting is an RSS feed?

Comment: `$http.get` is essentially the same as jQuery's `$.get`, only it plays nicely with Angular.

Comment: This returns as an object and not as a XML feed. $.get returns correctly $http.get does not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95383/discussion-between-justin-powell-and-coded-container).