# Retrieve get response http angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am a beginner in angular and I want to retrieve the http get response of an url (http://myurl.com) to make after some manipulations.

I test that but no result :/

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('myService', function($http) {
  return {
    async: function() {
     return $http.get('http://apibuilder-apidiscovery.kermit.rd.francetelecom.fr/infrastructures/16857');
    }
  };
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function( myService,$scope) {
  myService.async().then(function(d) { //2. so you can use .then()
    $scope.data = d;
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        Data: {{data}}<br>
    </div>
</body>
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you checked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369377/how-to-use-http-get-in-angularjs-correctly-in-specific-for-an-external-api-cal

Answer (score 1):

The data assignment should be `$scope.data = d.data;`

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function( myService,$scope) {
  myService.async().then(function(d) { //2. so you can use .then()
    $scope.data = d.data;
  }, function(error){
     console.log('Error occured');
  });
});
```

> **Note** also make sure that if you are trying to make call to external domain, the `CORS` should be enabled. Additionally you might need to pass autherization headers in the request.

Answer (score 0):

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('myService', function($http,$q) {

    var myService = {
        async : async,
    };
    return myService;

    function async() {
        var d = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://apibuilder-apidiscovery.kermit.rd.francetelecom.fr/infrastructures/16857',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "text/plain",
                // you can add headers here
            }
        }).then(function(reply) {
            d.resolve(reply.data);
        }, function(error) {
            d.reject(error.data);
        });
        return d.promise;
    }

});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function(myService, $scope) {

  myService.async()
    .then(function(result) {
        $scope.data = result;
  });

});
```

and the index file,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    Data: {{data}}<br>
  </body>

</html>
```