# How do I call an Angular JS HTTP GET?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I have an internship where I will be required to use Angular JS HTTP, I want to make sure I can get it to work.

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("data.json")
});
</script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
  <li ng-repeat="name in Person">{{name.Name}}</li>
</div>
```

And my JSON file

```
{
  "Name": "Daniel"
}
```

Thanks,

I'm not sure how to link the url for the JSON file.

Comment: Have you tried actually running the code yet? That would surely be the easiest way to see if it works...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use HTTP.GET in AngularJS correctly? In specific, for an external API call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369377/how-to-use-http-get-in-angularjs-correctly-in-specific-for-an-external-api-cal)

Comment: Start a server (preferably one that talks http) that delivers `data.json`?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#general-usage

Comment: The problem with the suggested duplicate is most of the answers use the deprecated `.success` and `.then` methods and the one that uses the `.then` method is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

An esay way to start a [http](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)-server, if you have [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) on your system, is to use the package [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server). Below is an example using [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) as package manger.

```
yarn global add http-server
cd $TO_THE_DIRECTORY_CONTAINING_DATA.JSON
http-server .
```

And then you have `data.json` at: http://localhost:8080/data.json